# Similar looking sum and integral for the same function

Tags: integration, summation

I've recently become aware that if $f(x) = ax + b$, then
$$\sum_{i = 0}^nf(i) = \frac{1}{2}(n + 1)(an + 2b)$$
while
$$\int_{0}^{n}f(t)\,dt = \frac{1}{2} n(an + 2b).$$
These two look suspiciously similar to me. Is there something going on here or is it just a coincidence? Are there functions for which
$$\sum_{i = 0}^nf(i) = \int_{0}^{n}f(t)\,dt$$
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Note that the sum has $n+1$ terms while the integral covers a length of $n$.  This means that constant functions do not satisfy this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One choice is to start with $f(0)=0$, then have $f(x)$ constant for $x \gt 0$  Another is to define $g(x)$ as any integrable function on $[0,\infty)$, then choose $f(x)=g(x)$ for $x \not \in \Bbb Z$ and choose $f$ on the integers to make the sum come out equal to the integral.  Changing the value of a function at points does not change the integral.

Comment: Hmm I was actually more interested in the first question about whether linear functions had some weird property hitherto unknown to me, it's my own fault for asking two questions though.

Answer (score 4):

Hint. Draw pictures that illustrate the two areas: one a triangle, one a sequence of rectangles. Just the case $a = b= 1$ should be instructive.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=ax+b$$
$$\begin{align}\sum_{i=0}^nf(i)=&a\sum_{i=0}^ni+b\sum_{i=0}^n1\\
=&a\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+b(n+1)\\
=&\frac12(n+1)\left(an+2b\right)\end{align}$$

---

$$\begin{align}\int_0^nf(x)\,\mathrm dx=&\int_0^n(ax+b)\,\mathrm dx\\
=&\left[\frac a2x^2+bx\right]_0^n\\
=&\frac12n(an+2b)\end{align}$$

---

An integral can be thought of as an infinite sum of finite area elements to give the total area. It might be easier to split this into two pieces:
$$\int_0^nf(x)\,\mathrm dx=\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^kf(x^*_i)\Delta x_i$$
where you can take upper, lower and middle Riemann sums. You might want to try this for yourself using all three. You can think of $\Delta x_i$ as a discrete $\mathrm dx$ and it is going to be equally divided, each "strip" having a width of the domain divided by the number of strips, so:
$$\Delta x_i=\frac nk$$
and obviously $f(x_i)$ is going to vary depending on where within the strip we take the value, I would recommend reading into Riemann integrals and sums as this will explain what you are looking for, here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5XreKMJDJsg). And here is the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20Riemann%20sum,of%20curves%20and%20other%20approximations.).

---

PS sorry for the rushed answer I have ran out of time